# Como fazer uma máscara em JavaScript para o type tel?

Tags: javascript, html5

Galera, é o seguinte: criei um formulário e um campo para o usuário preencher seu telefone. Ou seja: campo type="tel". O que eu quero é um código em JavaScript que, quando o usuário inserir o telefone, o código automaticamente transforme o telefone para este formato (xx) xxxx-xxxx. Resumindo: eu quero que o código preencha automaticamente os parenteses, o espaço e o hifen, deixando o telefone assim:

(xx) xxxx-xxxx

Obs: respeitando os parenteses, o espaço e o hífen.

Outra dúvida: tem como fazer isso com o próprio HTML?

Se puderem, postem a parte do HTML na qual eu chamo o método, pois ainda não estudei JavaScript. Obrigada.

Answer (score -1):

Sim, você pode fazer diretamente em HTML5 através do parâmetro `pattern` e usando uma expressão regular:

```
<input type="text" id="tel" pattern="\([0-9]{2}\) [0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}">
```

Neste caso o navegador irá considerar válido os valores que casarem com este padrão. Se você quiser validar números de telefone celular você trocar o primeiro `[0-9]{4}` por `[0-9]{5}` ou então para `[0-9]{4,5}` se quiser validar ambos.

Comment: O que significam essas duas "\" ?

Comment: Tenha em mente que a pergunta fala em mascara especificamente e não validação.

Comment: Martha, em expressão regular os parênteses são usados na sintaxe, o "\(" é para ele ser interpretado como um caractere comum.

Answer (score -1):

Para fazer máscaras de tel, cnpj e cpf existem diversos modos, vou te apresentar um que é alterando o texto já digitado, tratando ele como um array e inserindo os caracteres especiais de máscara..

```
var tel = document.getElementById('SEU INPUT')
tel.addEventListener('change',() => {
    const telFormatA = tel.value.split('')
    telFormatA.splice(0,0,'(')
    telFormatA.splice(3,0,')')
    telFormatA.splice(9,0,'-')

    const telA = telFormatA.join('')

    document.getElementById('telefone-usuario').value = telA
});
```

Desse jeito o número que for digitado do jeito 99999999999 vai virar (99)99999-9999 é uma máscara simples, mas você pode usar ela como base para coisas mais complexas.

Answer (score -1):

Eu tenho um funciona. Identifica se é número fixo ou celular e já permite a quantidade de caracteres necessárias.
Se começar com numero 9, ele já deduz que é número móvel e destina a quantidade de caracteres, caso contrário destina a quantidade de caracteres para numero fixo.
segue o código:

```js
const maskPhoneNumber = (value) => {
  if (!value) return ''

  return value
    .replace(/[\D]/g, '')
    .replace(/(\d{2})(\d)/, '($1) $2')
    .replace(value[5] != 9 ? /(\d{4})(\d)/ : /(\d{5})(\d)/, '$1-$2')
    .replace(/(-\d{4})(\d+?)/, '$1')
}

const applyPhoneNumberMask = (input) => {
  input.value = maskPhoneNumber(input.value)
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="phone" oninput="applyPhoneNumberMask(this)">
```

Comment: Queria saber o motivo de sinalizar negativamente, se o código funciona perfeitamente.

Comment: Funcionou aqui!